# how to use two stop event in jquery ui spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

In the below code I need to execude show_error method with debounce (delay) and show_value method without delay.

Both methods needs in stop event only how to do it ?

```
$("#test").spinner({
 stop: function(event , ui){
 show_value();
  },
 stop: _.debounce(function(e, ui) {
      show_error();

    }, 300)
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call both functions in a single handler:

```
var debouncedStop = _.debounce(function(e, ui) {
      show_error();
}, 300);
$("#test").spinner({
 stop: function(event, ui){
     show_value();
     debouncedStop();
 }
});
```

Or bind them separately:

```
$("#test").spinner()
          .on("spinstop", function(event , ui) {
              show_value();
          })
          .on("spinstop", _.debounce(function(e, ui) {
              show_error();
          }, 300));
```